# Is there a way i can use a variable from an index in a module.exports file?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I am currently working on a discord bot with a command handler so all the commands are in separate files. I can't figure out how to use variables from the index like `Discord` and `client` in the command file.

This is what a command looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
    commands: ['say', 'say'],
    expectedArgs: 'Announcement...',
    minArgs: 1,
    permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
    requiredRoles: [],
    callback: async (message, args, text) => {

        const { member } = message
        const tag = `<@${member.id}>`
    
          const announce = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('RANDOM')
          .setTitle(`ANNOUNCMENT!`)
          .setFooter(config.footer)
          .setDescription(`${tag} __Announces:__\n **${args}**`)
          .setThumbnail(config.logo)
          
            message.delete()
            message.channel.send(announce)
    
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best method, but I solved this issue by exporting the `Client` in `module.exports` in the main file, index in your case, and importing the index in the command file.

---

```js
// Your index file.
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_AUTH_TOKEN);

module.exports.client = client;
```

```js
// Command file.
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Index = require("path to index");
module.exports = {
    commands: ['say', 'say'],
    expectedArgs: 'Announcement...',
    minArgs: 1,
    permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
    requiredRoles: [],
    callback: async (message, args, text) => {
        console.log(`Running as ${Index.client.user.tag}!`);
    },
}
```

Another way to do this is to pass your  `client` variable alongside `message`, `args` and `text` when you are running the `callback` function.